# Red Color selection in Python and Skimage

Tags: python, image-processing

I'm trying to load an image from the disk and then to extract just the red channel of it and display it in grayscale with grey colormap but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.. The image should be displayed as an rgb color, but if I'm using convert_colorspace it doesn't work.. This is my code:

```
# Import skimage and matplotlib
from skimage import io,color
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Image loading
img = io.imread('lena.png')
# Displaying the original image
plt.figure(),plt.imshow(img)

# Grayscale conversion
converted_img = color.convert_colorspace(,'RGB','RGB CIE')
# Data type of the grayscale image
# taking the red channel
#red_channel=[:,:,2]
plt.figure(),plt.imshow(converted_img)
```

Answer (score 1):

The *convert_colorspace()* function requires array as its first parameter (check the [documentation](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.color.html#skimage.color.convert_colorspace)), something you did not provide it with. Simply passing the image whose colorspace you want to change as the first argument would fix the problem:

```
converted_img = color.convert_colorspace(img, 'RGB','RGB CIE')
```

Based on your code's comments, I think you might be confused as to why you apply *convert_colorspace()*. In this case this will not convert the image to grayscale but simply to another representation of RGB, known  as [RGB CIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1931_color_space). Furthermore, if you want to grab only one of the image's channels, in this case red, you should not grayscale the image. Keep in mind that *skimage* loads images as *numpy.ndarray* with a shape of (X, Y, 3). Therefore, you can grab the red channel as follows:

```
red_channel = converted_img[:,:,0]
```

Here is the result of plotting only the image's red channel:
[image]

Complete code:

```
# Imports:
from skimage import io, color
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = io.imread('lena.png')
# Displaying the original image:
plt.figure(), plt.imshow(img)

# Colorspace conversion:
converted_img = color.convert_colorspace(img, 'RGB', 'RGB CIE')
# Taking the red channel:
red_channel = converted_img [:,:,0]
# Displaying the converted image's red channel:
plt.figure(), plt.imshow(red_channel, cmap="gray")
```